# Inheriting a method from the ancestor's ancestor

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I am working on a component that is derived from a commercial component suite, and have run into a challenge, which I've never considered before. Consider the following code snippet:

```
TMyClass = class
protected
  procedure SomeMethod; virtual;
end;

TMyClass1 = class(TMyClass)
protected
  procedure SomeMethod; override;
end;

TMyMode = (mmOne, mmTwo);
TMyClass2 = class(TMyClass1)
private
  FMode: TMyMode;
protected
  procedure SomeMethod; override;
public
  property Mode: TMyMode read FMode write FMode;
end;

...

procedure TMyClass2.SomeMethod;
begin
  if FMode = mmOne then inherited SomeMethod
                   else inherited TMyClass.SomeMethod;
end;
```

So if Mode = mmOne then I inherit as normal, but if it is mmTwo, I still want to inherit the code from my ancestor's ancestor, but not what was introduced in the ancestor. I've tried the above, with no success, and since I've never encountered this before, I gather it's not possible. Any takers?

Comment: I don't want to be a killjoy but I'd rather rearrange my code a bit so that the need for this construct vanishes - split one or two of the methods, add a parameter or something else.

Comment: I agree - there is always a danger of issues downstream when losing inheritance. However, I don't have control over the commercial components. I could change their code accordingly, but that leave me with a downstream maintenance issue whenever I upgrade the component suite (DevExpress). And for this specific scenario, I think it's the best way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with class helpers:

```
type
  TA = class
  public
    procedure X; virtual;
  end;

  TB = class(TA)
  public
    procedure X; override;
  end;

  TA_Helper = class helper for TA
    procedure A_X;
  end;

  TC = class(TB)
  public
    procedure X; override;
  end;

procedure TA.X;
begin
  // ...
end;

procedure TB.X;
begin
  // ...
end;

procedure TA_Helper.A_X;
begin
  inherited X; // TA.X
end;

procedure TC.X;
begin
  A_X;
  inherited X; // TB.X
end;
```

I think class helpers exist in D2006, but if they don't, you can also use a hack to the same effect:

```
// ...
  TA_Helper = class(TA)
    procedure A_X;
  end;
// ...
procedure TC.X;
begin
  TA_Helper(Self).A_X;
  inherited X; // TB.X
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, hvd. This has got to be the world's best kept secret. You've saved me hours!

Answer (score 4):

there is another solution of this task without class-helpers or additional methods (as in @hvd answer). you can get base class methods code address and invoke it with `self` Data-pointer:
**updated code, without rtti**

```
unit Unit4;

interface
type
    TA = class(TObject)
      protected
        procedure Test(); virtual;
    end;

    TB = class(TA)
      protected
        procedure Test(); override;
    end;

    TC = class(TB)
      public
        procedure Test(); override;
    end;

implementation

procedure TA.Test;
begin
    writeln('TA.Test()');
end;

procedure TB.Test;
begin
    writeln('TB.Test');
end;

procedure TC.Test;
var TATest : procedure of object;
begin
    writeln('TC.Test();');
    writeln('call inherited TB: ');
    inherited Test();


    writeln('call inherited TA:');
    TMethod(TATest).Data := self;
    TMethod(TATest).Code := @TA.Test;
    TATest();
end;
end.
```

Comment: of course TRTTIContext does not exist in d2006, but there is an old rtti unit, wich you can use to get code-pointer to `TA.Test` method

Comment: I don't think you can access those methods with RTTI in D2006 at all, unless the methods are `published`.

Comment: @hvd yes, seems like that. But I found that I overcomlicated code above; there is no need to use RTTI (don't know about D2006, but in 2010 works fine). I've updated the answer;

Comment: Yes, that looks like it should work, and you might even be able to do simplify it to something like `type TTestProc = procedure(Self: TA); TTestProc(@TA.Test)(Self);` -- untested :)

Comment: Oh, I forgot, I'm actually not sure that (and your current solution) will work at all if the virtual method is `protected` and `TA` is in a different unit.

Comment: i'll test it with the different unit :) and it is already in `protected` section

Comment: I've just tried in DelphiXE2, all 3 classes in separate units, `Test` is `protected` in TA&TB. it works fine.

Comment: Also looking good in XE. It's tricky, other languages disallow access to TA.Test because you might use it to call Test on a TA that isn't a TC, but luckily Delphi doesn't mind.

Comment: This is very neat. Thank you, gentlemen. I did manage to juggle it to work with helpers, but I think this might be cleaner. I'm going to play around with it a bit more.